# Cassandra generates "OutOfMemory" Error on nodes startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

We are running a 3 node cassandra cluster on AWS. I am able to start one node but i am failing to start other two nodes in the cluster.
Whenver i try to start the node, i get a list of following information until it finally runs out of heap space and terminates:
http://pastebin.com/7gRGWVDV

Finally, nodes terminate with out of memory error:

```
ERROR 07:37:41,495 Exception in thread Thread[FileWatchdog,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:916)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.checkAndConfigure(FileWatchdog.java:77)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:108) 
ERROR 07:37:48,570 Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:4,1,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.readBytes(RandomAccessReader.java:347)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:392)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:355)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserializeColumnBody(ColumnSerializer.java:124)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.OnDiskAtom$Serializer.deserializeFromSSTable(OnDiskAtom.java:85)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:75)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:64)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:153)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.IndexedSliceReader$IndexedBlockFetcher.getNextBlock(IndexedSliceReader.java:434 )
```

In cassandra-env.sh , i set :

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
```

I was able to start the cassandra and run it properly till few days back and then we ran a data migration task which moves data from mysql to cassandra. During that migration, i remember we have moved about 40 million rows from mysql to cassandra. As a result of that, we ran out of hard disk space and hence we added more disk space and bumped up our aws instances from m3 large to m3 xlarge.
But now i am unable to start the nodes. 
As suggested in other SO answers, i deleted the saved_cache directory and tried to restart the nodes. But this suggestion did not work for us.

I am using cassandra version 2.0.14

Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same thing a few times. Basically, Cassandra consumes a lot of heap during large inserts due to compaction. Try starting with a larger heap, and lower it again, once the imports are done